# Hiding content with "php if", but content partially not showing when there is content (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using below code to hide the whole div (lgst-box) when there is no content in a wordpress custom field (rh_woo_code_zone('content')):

```
<?php if ( rh_woo_code_zone('content') ) : ?>
  <div class="lgst-box" id="veelgestelde-vragen">
    <div class="box-title mb15">
      <h2 class="text-upper">Veelgestelde Vragen</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
      <?php rh_woo_code_zone('content');?> 
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, when there IS actually content, it's displaying that perfectly fine, but it's showing it in plain text without the div's and the h2 tag. It's hiding it when there is no content btw so that works.

How it should be showing:
[image]

But how it actually shows:
[image]

Comment: The function `rh_woo_code_zone('content')` itself echos the content. What you see is the output that was already generated in the `if` clause. This is nothing that can be fixed with this code (apart from going the full `ob_start()` route). Look into your theme’s/plugin’s documentation, if there is something like a `rh_woo_exists('content')` function or similar.

Comment: I fixed it by switching from the theme in-built fields to ACF fields and those work as expected with my above code. Thank you for pointing out that it has to do with my theme.